# Research Article Submission

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, journals

I got my article with major revision from "Renewable Energy" but as per my knowledge the major revision are seen to be like minor questions were asked by the two reviewers. After submitting my revised manuscript, after 15 days my status was in "under review" the next day it was changed to "required reviews completed". Now so far, for 16 days my article still in "required reviews completed". Why is the editor taking very long time after the second review completed? Please, any one of you gives me the answer.

Why you all people have marked the duplicate of an existing question. My question may be old to everyone, But this question what I raised is new to me....if you are willing to give the proper answer to the question, I am very thankful to them. But don't say existing question for what I asked

Comment: @SolarMike There are plenty of reasons when your assertion is absolutely wrong. It would never happen. It should rather be accepted than waiting for a decision.

Comment: @coder these are comments....

Comment: It's sometimes regarded as a bit of an outdated concept, but have you tried a bit of *patience*?

Comment: @Coder, Enthusiastic User, Buzz, Ander Biguri, Florian D'Souza: Why you people have marked the duplicate of an existing question. My question may be old to everyone, But this question what I raised is new to me....if you are willing to give the proper answer to the question, I am very thankful to them. But don't say existing question for what I asked

Comment: @M.VijayKumar We understand your concern. The identical question has already got some answers. So, it should be marked as duplicate as per academia.SE policies to avoid redundancies. Also, here you already have got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that "Required Reviews Completed" status does not entail that "all" reviews are completed. It just suggests that a "minimal" set of reviews have come in.

For example, for few journals, the required number of reviews to make a decision could be 2; but, sometimes the editor sends an article to more than 2 reviewers. In that case, if he is not satisfied with the received reviews (i.e. at least two), then he waits for the few more.

In my recent paper, the status remained as it is for 2.5 months. Then, I reminded the journal EIC to expedite the process. Still, I had to wait for a month to receive the final decision.